# Using positional operator with two-level hierarchies in Mongo

Tags: mongodb

I have a hierarchy of, let say, `posts -> comments -> votes`.

How do I update a certain vote on certain comment?
For comment it is `comments.$`, but I obviously can't do `comments.$.votes.$`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cann't do it right now(there is such [bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831?focusedCommentId=22438&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel) in jira). But i suppose you can update using server side side javascript. Check this [article](http://vasilrem.com/blog/software-development/stored-javascript-in-mongo/) for more details.

Another way it redesign your db scheme to one level deep, for example in case of post-> comments-> votes move comments(or even votes) in separate collection.

Comment: Did you mean to say "you can _not_ do it"? It seems so since the bug is still open, but I just want to make sure I understand correctly.

Comment: I'd suggest being careful with javascript like that since it restricts concurrency (all js runs in a single thread) and creates a global lock by default.

Comment: The article referenced is now a broken link